# $\lambda^{*}(A \cup B) = \lambda^{*}(A) + \lambda^{*}(B)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint, closed subets of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that if both $A$ and $B$ are closed and bounded disjoints of $\mathbb{R}$, then;

$$\lambda^{*}(A \cup B) = \lambda^{*}(A) + \lambda^{*}(B)$$

where $\lambda^{*}$ is the outer Lebesgue measure.

This is the question we've been asked in a problem sheet. I've shown this equality holds for $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ being disjoint and $\text{dist}(A,B)>0$,as well as $A,B$ being disjoint intervals. However, this last one is confusing me a lot.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500791/proving-lambdaa-cup-b-lambdaa-lambdab?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving $ \lambda^{*}(A \cup B) = \lambda^{*}(A)+\lambda^{*}(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500791/proving-lambdaa-cup-b-lambdaa-lambdab)

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are closed and disjoint subsets of $\mathbb R$, then $dist(A,B) > 0$.

Comment: @amsmath This is not true. For example $A=\bigcup_{n=3}^\infty [n-\frac{2}{n}, n-\frac{1}{n}]$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Eclipse Sun You are right. I was thinking about bounded sets. A simpler example is $A = \{n+\tfrac 1 n : n\in\mathbb Z\}$ and $B = \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If you already know a bit about measurable sets, this is rather straightforward. So we only assume the definition.

Take a closed interval $I=[a,b]$ of $\mathbb{R}$. The  subsets $A\cap I$ and $B\cap I$ are compact and disjoint, so $d(A\cap I, B\cap I) = \delta_I>0$. Divide $I$ into finitely many intervals of length $< \delta_I$. Each of these subintervals intersects at most one of the sets $A$, $B$.

Consider now a sequence of intervals $I_n$ whose union cover $A\cup B$. For each $n$, divide $I_n$ into finitely many intervals that intersect at most one of the subsets $A$, $B$. Consider now all the subintervals that intersect $A$, and all those that intersect $B$, call them $I'_k$, and $I_l''$. We have 
$$\sum |I_n| \ge \sum |I'_k| + \sum |I_l''| \ge \lambda^{\star}(A) + \lambda^{\star}(B)$$